# Fix broken linux-headers package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I've accidentally run `sudo apt remove linux-image-unsigned-5.14.1-051401-generic`

and prompted to a <kbd><YES></kbd> + <kbd><NO></kbd> optinonal screen saying that it's my kernel version currently running.

I've tried downloading the files with the same version in [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.14.10/amd64/) and do `apt install *.deb` and do restart.

now there's is a **red-broken-package** icon saying some package broken, when I do `apt update` it says I need to reinstall headers package.

`--fix-broken install` result :

```bsh
ainul@ainul-Swift-SF314-43:~ $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for ainul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.14.10-051410-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 23,3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

reinstall result :

```bsh
ainul@ainul-Swift-SF314-43:~ $ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.14.10-051410-generic 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of linux-headers-5.14.10-051410-generic is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-5.14.10-051410-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

is there any way I can fix the headers ? Im worried that it will causing error removing the kernel currently running

Comment: well yes but it prompted me to a yes or no screen saying its the running kernel

Comment: I'm using 20.04

Comment: oh god, thank you. It's not prompted me to a optional screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130957/discussion-between-algnis-and-ainulbedjo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `y` when it says to remove that package (`apt --fix-broken install`)

Comment: Im really embarased at myself, worried about my work folder in the laptop. Thank you